# How to fix message converter miss understanding object type for Jackson parsing

Tags: spring-jms, jmstemplate

I setting up `MessageConverter` with `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` for `JmsTemplate`. Where do I expect that I can cast message to my object class but it does not happened!

I write `MessageConverter` as follow that it used for my `JmsTemplate` sending message method and listener factory (`setMessageConverter`) as follow

```
private MessageConverter messageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    messageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return messageConverter;
}
```

and my Object class is

```
public class RequestMessage<T> implements Serializable {
    String ticket;
    T detail;
    // getter , setter & toString
}
```

but after consuming `RequestMessage<Foo>` with `@JmsListener` it can not cast `Foo` because `Jackson` change it to `LinkedHashMap`.

I will appropriated any hint or answers.